# File can not be copied to response steam

Tags: java, spring, request, response, fileinputstream

There is an interesting error on a page. I wonder if you have any idea about it.

In order to download a file, we write the file to `responseStream` but if file is less than 8,3KB, we get file not found error although file is there.

If i increase the file size (using some dummy values), it works

I suspect it has something to do with the `contentLength` of response but it seems fine to me

```
    file = new File(ef.getPath());
        response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
        fileIs = new FileInputStream(file);
        FileCopyUtils.copy(fileIs, response.getOutputStream());
```

Please help me if you have any idea?

Comment: What do calls like file.isFile(), file.exists(), file.canRead() result in? What IS this 'ef' variable you're using anyway?

Comment: What does `FileCopyUtils.copy(...)` return?

Answer (score -1):

How try with adding `Content-Disposition` header and `setContentType()`

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+ fileName + "\"");
String mimeType = new MimetypesFileTypeMap().getContentType(fileName);
response.setContentType(mimetype);
```